# Frequently changing UI in mobile applications

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, mobile-application

I have been working on Mobile Applications and developing several types of UIs. But I frequently face a question regarding dynamic UIs.
In **E-Commerce apps or Food Delivery Apps**, we generally see that the UI changes quite often (with new offers, items, festival sales, etc. shown and removed) and is not static (**like we generally code a UI with different views/widgets, which show dynamic data**). So, my question is how the UI is made dynamic in this sense without pushing new updates to the apps?
Also, how we can develop such a UI in **Flutter?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's been a few years since I did any Android development, but I suspect most apps you're referring to probably use a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/webview) as their primary component, enabling them to serve mobile-friendly HTML/JavaScript/CSS content for the app to render.

Some apps probably mix static UI components with WebViews for portions they need to be dynamic and change frequently.

Comment: Almost none of them use a WebView.  They're almost all native in my experience.  It will be a custom component crafter to get data from a server, but display it natively.  WebViews are kept at arms length for a variety of reasons, especially if there's personalized content there.  I've never seen one used for front page or sale listings in major apps.